# Find specific path inside a jar

Tags: linux, class, unix, jar, find

I got a jar file, and I know a class name in it for sure.
I need to know, in case this class file is in folder inside that jar, a command @Unix, in which I can see the full path of that class file where in that jar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
jar tf TicTacToe.jar
```

For additional information you can do

```
jar tvf TicTacToe.jar
```